# I am getting an error when I am splitting a string into 2 words and swapping them

Tags: java

Here is the issue i am running into

```
    System.out.println("Please enter the student's name in the form of Doe, John or Smith, Jane");
    name = keyboard.next();
    int index = name.indexOf(",");
    String firstWord = name.substring(0,index); // Cuts the first word from the string
    int lastIndex = (name.lastIndexOf(","))+1;
    String lastWord = name.substring(lastIndex,name.length());// Cuts the last word of the string
    switchedName = lastWord+" , "+firstWord; 
    return switchedName;
```

This will return the string switched around but only if it is inputed as Doe,John if I enter a space between the name(ex. Doe, John) it will immediately crash after the name is entered and it is being called in the next line of code which is just a println statement

Comment: Explain what you mean by crash. Seg fault? Exception? If exception, print it here...

Comment: You are not declaring a type for name or switched name.  That will cause an error at compile time.

Comment: also, aren't you supposed to use a scanner to get user input?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `name = keyboard.next();` you should do `name = keyboard.nextLine();`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
name = keyboard.next();
```

to

```
name = keyboard.nextLine();
```

next() will only return what comes before a space.

So your Doe, ( space ) John will return you the half of it

nextLine() returning the current line

Answer (score 1):

For the input Use the nextLine instead of next to read what is after the space character.
You didnt create switchedName before instanciation.

> > String switchedName = lastWord+" , "+firstWord;